# Emacs cut in Intellij 13.1 on Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have 'Emacs' selected in Preferences > Keymap

Edit > Cut from the menu bar works fine. The keymap indicates that the shortcut for cut is <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> ... but that does *not* work fine. Doing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> on some text and then Edit > Paste does not work properly (it pastes something else). Doing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> and some text and then alt P (the paste shortcut) does not work properly.

alt C and alt P (copy/paste) *do* work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure why shift+delete doesn't work. Maybe this combination is not allowed as keyboard shortcut on Mac. However, you can use ctrl+w to cut the selection region and then ctrl+y to paste it.

Comment: Okay , that's a good workaround. Thanks :-)